# Showing text horizontally to image with multiple images verticaaly alliagned

Tags: android

I want to show text horizontally to image with multiple images vertically alliagned .
Thislayout is not throwing any exception but only one image is coming ..other two images are not coming up in my layout .

my layout xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"

     >
<ScrollView  android:id="@+id/scrollviewmotherregister" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:layout_marginTop="2dip"  android:layout_marginBottom="2dip">

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
 >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/icici"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="ICICI Bank"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Timings : 9 AM to 5 PM"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Contact Number : 9894198941"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>




    </LinearLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/indianbank"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/hdfc"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="HDFC Bank "
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Timings : 10 AM to 6 PM"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:text="Contact Number : 9740999443"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>




    </LinearLayout>

     <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/axisbank"
        android:layout_width="90dip"
        android:layout_height="90dip"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dip"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dip"
        android:src="@drawable/axis"
         >
    </ImageView>

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:orientation="vertical"
     >

     <TextView

        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    </TextView>
      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Axis Bank"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

      <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Timings : 9:30 AM to 5:30 PM"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>

     <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label5"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contact Number : 9003245643"
        android:textSize="20dip" >
    </TextView>




    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Problem :

```
I am getting first images but other two images are not showing up .
```

Comment: Is it ambigious anywhere ....Please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Take a scroll view inside that linear layout of scroll view take a different linear horizontal layout,,,than on each orizontal layout take one image +text view...

Answer (score 0):

Every `LinearLayout` **containing the TextViews** set each layout's Width to `WRAP_CONTENT` from the `FILL_PARENT`

Cause the first LinearLayout with TextViews are showing up..and after that the whole space is taken by the first LinearLayout - that's Fill_Parent so..need to change it to Wrap-Content.

This is what it looks like to me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try RelativeLayout under LinearLayout. RelativeLayout has all aligned properties that will help your target.